# C++ ; fatal error: 'format' file not found #include <format>. Cppstandard C++23 does not seem to work for me

Tags: c++, format, c++23

New to C++. Coding on Mac Catalina. VSCode Version: 1.85.2 (Universal).
Following online course and one lesson is to specifically see if `#include <format>` works.
It does not.

Code>>

```
#include <format> 
#include <iostream>

using std::format;
using std::cout;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```

---

Errors >>

1. #include errors detected based on information provided by the configurationProvider setting. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/Users/.../.../main.cpp).
2. cannot open source file "format"
3. 'format' file not found

---

I have setup VSCode, downloaded the C++ extensions, changed to C++23 via cppstandard under extension. I see threads such as [can't include std::format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017719/cant-include-stdformat) that recommend

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
```

However, since reference lesson used cppstandard c++20 I figured mine would work as well.
A regular hello world without

```
#include <format>
```

works just fine.

Perhaps relevant settings from settings.json.

```
Settings.json
    "C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang++",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++23"
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  VSCode is an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Apple clang only supports format from version 15, which version are you using? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support your errors look like intellisense errors, have you tried compiling the code? Do you get the same errors? What compiler command line are you using?

Comment: Yes, you're correct Nathan.

Alan, that is very interesting. So it is possible my clang is outdated? 

`Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

upon removing `#include <format>` and `using std::format` I can compile it with a return code 0.

Under launch.json it says name: `"C/C++: clang++ build and debug active file"`, `"version": "2.0.0"` at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to update your compiler, or you can get an updated non-apple gcc or clang via homebrew.

Comment: Ok. I will dig into that. Thank you!

Comment: I run Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2026) thus I get that warning from Homebrew that it is not supported. However, I have brew now. Homebrew 4.2.6. According to https://releases.llvm.org/ there is a version 17.0.6, is it foolish to run a `brew install llvm@17.0.6` in able to get a more recent version of clang? EDIT: Found https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/llvm#default, it is not compatible. Will look further.

Comment: If this is the only problem, there are other ways to get the format library. You can get it on github or use boost::format.

Comment: You're right. I'm going off topic. I will consider this done and find a way to use a format library such as fmt.

Comment: I'd use the Victor Zverovich [`{fmt}`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library, which can be used with earlier versions (standards) of C++ before the subset of the `{fmt}` was added to C++20.  I consider `{fmt}` to be fuller-featured, even though it (perhaps) hasn't been as carefully scrutinized, honed & polished as what goes into the standard (...as I hope & believe).  I'm using `{fmt}` with C++17, and it's been great.

Comment: Eljay, thank you. I have included the core.h locally as my #include <fmt/core.h> doesn't seem to work even if the folder is inside the project, and then fmt::format() works, so I'm satisfied as of now. I'll dive deeper into that when I'm a better C++ programmer.